# How to display a message after socket is disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, disconnect

I'm making a two player interactive game with node, p5.js & sockets.io

I have limited the number of clients to two in the server.js, with:

```
if (client.length>2){
socket.disconnect(client[2]);}
```

How can I get the browser to display text **“there are more than 2 users, try again later”**, on the **client[2]** page when it’s already disconnected?

I tried:

`socket.emit(‘sorry’, {sryMessage: ‘there are more than 2 users’})` 
in the server.

And in the client.js: (using p5.js)

```
Function draw(){
        socket.on(‘sorry’, function(sryMessage){
     fill(255);
       textSize(32);
    text(sryMessage, 200, height/2);
    })
}
```

Is this the right way to approach it?
Because the Websocket is closed & disconnected before the connection is established and I can display a message